# MongoDB - Get arrays with distinct

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I'm trying to get all the values(which are arrays) of the "coordinate" type in my data like that:

```
[
["51.50064317423898","-0.09372711181640626"],
["51.48465408363687","-0.13149261474609378"]
]
```

I tried db.collections("mydb").distinct("coordinate") but i get:

```
[
  '-0.09372711181640626',
  '-0.13149261474609378',
  '51.48465408363687',
  '51.50064317423898'
]
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can just have all my arrays like i want and not ordered in one array?
"mydb" looks like this:

```
{
"name":"dfbfdbf",
"coordinate":["51.50064317423898","-0.09372711181640626"],
"rating":"8",
"description":"geojzglijsen"
},
{
"name":"qzfgs",
"coordinate":["51.48465408363687","-0.13149261474609378"],
"rating":"5",
"description":"femkndsmnk"
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try this aggregate query:

The point is `$group` by `null` to get all values and use `$addToSet` which prevents the duplicates values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "coordinate": {
        "$addToSet": "$coordinate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P08W33DnsN3) where I've duplicated one object to see how the repeated value is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch distinct coordinates from your collection:

```
mongos> db.a.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea12e032deead586f3f91"), "name" : "dfbfdbf", "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea138032deead586f3f92"), "name" : "a", "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea14c032deead586f3f93"), "name" : "a", "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.19372711181640626" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea157032deead586f3f94"), "name" : "a", "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea15b032deead586f3f95"), "name" : "a", "coordinate" : [ "52.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619ea160032deead586f3f96"), "name" : "a", "coordinate" : [ "52.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
mongos> db.a.aggregate([ 
 { $addFields:{coordinates:{$reduce:{ input: {$slice:["$coordinate",1,{$size:"$coordinate"} ]},initialValue:{$arrayElemAt:["$coordinate",0]},in:{$concat:["$$value",";","$$this" ]}    }} }}    ,
 { $group:{_id:"$coordinates" , cnt:{$sum:1}}} ,
 { $project : { coordinate : { $split: ["$_id", ";"] } ,_id:0}}          
 ])
{ "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.19372711181640626" ] }
{ "coordinate" : [ "51.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
{ "coordinate" : [ "52.50064317423898", "-0.09372711181640626" ] }
mongos>
```

Example:
[here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RvRV5b1DoTe)

explained:
Remove duplicate coordinates from collection

1. create new field coordinates where you join the coordinates in single string
2. group the coordinates to remove duplicates
3. split the coordinates to the original values.

This solution has no limitation of distinct coordinates array summary size of  16MB as well ...